# Relation between $\eta\wedge \bar{\eta}\wedge \omega^{n-1}$ and $||\eta||^2\omega^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, differential-forms, kahler-manifolds

Let $X$ bet a compact Kahler manifold of dimension $\dim_{\mathbb{C}}(X)=n$ with Kahler form $\omega$. Let $\eta\in\Omega^{1,0}(X)$ be a differential form.

I would like to know if there is a way to relate the forms $\eta\wedge \bar{\eta}\wedge \omega^{n-1}$ and $||\eta||^2\omega^n$ or in a weaker way the integrals $\int_X\eta\wedge \bar{\eta}\wedge \omega^{n-1}$ and $\int_X||\eta||^2\omega^n$.

Comment: Here is an idea that I haven't thought through: Since $\eta \wedge \overline{\eta} \wedge \omega^{n-1}$ is a $2n$-form, one can write $\eta \wedge \overline{\eta} \wedge \omega^{n-1} = f\omega^n$ for some function $f$.  So, the question is to compute $f$ and relate it to $\Vert \eta \Vert^2$.  A place to start might be to note that $(\eta \wedge \overline{\eta} - f\omega) \wedge \omega^{n-1} = 0$ and then use either Cartan's Lemma or some algebra involving the Lefschetz isomorphisms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At any point $p\in M$, one choose a coordinates so that

$$ \omega = \sqrt{-1}\sum_i^n dz^i \wedge d\bar z ^i.$$

Note we have
$$ \omega^n = n! \sqrt{-1}^n dz^1\wedge d\bar z^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dz^n \wedge d\bar z^n.$$

Since $\eta\in \Omega^{1,0}$, one can write $\eta = \sum_i \eta_i dz^i$. Then

\begin{align}
\eta \wedge \bar \eta\wedge \omega^{n-1} &= \left( \sum_i \eta_i dz^i \right) \wedge \left( \sum_j \bar \eta_i d\bar z^j\right) \wedge \omega^{n-1}
\end{align}

One can check that if $i\neq j$,
$$ dz^i\wedge d\bar z^j \wedge \omega^{n-1} = 0.$$

Thus

\begin{align}
\eta \wedge \bar \eta\wedge \omega^{n-1} &= \left( \sum_i |\eta_i|^2 dz^i\wedge d\bar z^i \right)\wedge \omega^{n-1} \\
&= (n-1)!\sqrt{-1}^{n-1} |\eta|^2 dz^1\wedge d\bar z^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dz^n \wedge d\bar z^n \\
&=-\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{n} |\eta|^2 \omega^n. 
\end{align}